Trace of product of some special matrices
Suppose $u^i$, $v^i$ and $w$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $i=1,2,...,n$. Let $A$ be the matrix with entries $u^i \cdot u^j$, $B$ with entries $v^i \cdot v^j$ and $C$ with entries $w_i w_j$. I would like to know if the trace of $ACB$ is nonnegative or not.
In this case, $A$ and $B$ are Gram matrices, so they are positive semi-definite, and $C$ is also positive semi-definite. At the very beginning, I tried to show $ACB$ is positive semi-definite. However, I have found a counterexample to show $ACB$ is not positive semi-definite but the trace of $ACB$ is positive.

Assuming $B$ and $A$ don't commute: in general the product of two symmetric PSD matrices, $BA$, is not PSD; this means you can find some $\mathbf w \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $0\gt \mathbf w^TBA\mathbf w=\text{trace}\big(\mathbf w^TBA\mathbf w\big)=\text{trace}\big( A\mathbf {ww}^TB\big)=\text{trace}\big(ACB\big)$.  So rather than showing $ACB$ isn't PSD in general, this comes down to showing $BA$ isn't PSD in general.

You are right. The matrices $A$ and $B$ defined in the above may not be commutative. However, I do not know if their special forms would help or not.

There is nothing special stated about $A$ and $B$.  Every Gram Matrix (equivalently every real symmetric PSD matrix) can be written as $V^TV$ or $U^TU$.

Suppose $e$ is the all-ones vector and take $u_i=\lambda_i e$ and $v_i=\mu_i e$, where $\mu_i,\lambda_i$ are scalars. In this case,
$$trace(ACB)= trace(\lambda e^Te \lambda^T ww^T \mu e^Te \mu^T) = n^2 (\mu^T\lambda)(\lambda^T w)(\mu^T w).$$
Can you find three vectors $\mu,\lambda, w$ such that $(\mu^T\lambda)(\lambda^T w)(\mu^T w)<0$ ?
